# highest jump record distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

Assume $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ is $n$ record of height of jump of an athelete with i.i.d. distribution.

If we denote the $A_k = \{X_k>\sup_{j<k}X_j\}$ that new record of jump of this athlete appears at time k.

Prove that the current record is independent of future records.That is if $m_1<m_2<m_3<\ldots<m_k$. Then

$P(A_{m_1}\mid(A_{m_2}\cap A_{m_3}\cap\ldots\cap A_{m_k})) = P(A_{m_1}) $

This is an example from Durrett probability fourth edition textbook example 2.3.2.

I can't figure out how to get this result, my attempt is to marginalize the permutation but it fails.

Comment: Use the symmetry reasoning: no matter, conditionally on $A_{m_2}\cap\dots\cap A_{m_k}$ or not, any of $X_1,\dots,X_{m_1}$ can be largest with the same probability, so both sides of your equality are equal to $1/m_1$.

Comment: thanks, but I want a more rigorous one.

Comment: Yeah,I prefer your solution more.No bother to compute it.

Comment: You can consider some group of transformations which does not change the probabilities, leaves $A_{m_2},\dots, A_{m_k}$ intact, but permutes the first $m_1$ components (say, cycles on them). This way you will get that the probabilities (both unconditional and conditional on $A_{m_2}\cap \dots\cap A_{m_k}$) of events $\{X_i \text{ is largest among } X_1,\dots,X_{m_1}\}$, $i=1,\dots,m_1$, are identical, therefore, they are all equal to $1/m_1$. This kind of argument is very standard, so usually one simply appeals to "symmetry", which is considered rigorous enough.